# Problem when configuring S3 website domain go through Cloudflare DNS proxy

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudflare, ceph

Currently, I'm trying to create a CNAME record what points to a Ceph s3 website domain, for example:
`s3.example.com` => `s3.example.com.s3-website.myceph.com`. So in this way, my subdomain
`s3.` will have https.

But then only http works. If I go to https://s3.example.com, it shows the metadata of
index.html:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The
document tree is shown below.
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<Name>s3.example.com</Name>
<Prefix/>
<MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys>
<IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
<Contents>
<Key>index.html</Key>
<LastModified>2023-08-24T10:03:14.046Z</LastModified>
<ETag>"8e26caf000875221bf89d95f7f244927"</ETag>
<Size>295</Size>
<StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
<Owner>
<ID>d92ac19d934a4e9b90e7707372c64996</ID>
&lt;DisplayName&gt;foo(a)example.com&lt;/DisplayName&gt;
</Owner>
<Type>Normal</Type>
</Contents>
<Marker/>
</ListBucketResult>
```

Here is my rgw configuration:

```
rgw_resolve_cname = true
rgw_enable_static_website = true
rgw_dns_s3website_name = ss-website.example.com
rgw_trust_forwarded_https = true
```

So anyone know make the https show the content of index.html (not its metadata)? This issue doesn't occur using S3 website domain of AWS. Seems like it only happens
with Ceph.

Thanks in advance.